# PowerShell Adding Errors To An Array

Tags: arrays, powershell

So my larger project is to come up with a way of finding UNC path names that are too long, and once I have that information, use them as mapped drives so that I can run Get-Child information below that point.

I have the following code which gets me a Write of the folders that match that criteria, and display the UNC path to me, and I would like to add that information to an array that can be called back

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
Get-ChildItem "\\Server\Share" -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable err

foreach ($errorRecord in $err)
{
    if ($errorRecord.Exception -is [System.IO.PathTooLongException])
    {
        Write-Warning ($errorRecord.TargetObject)
        $ErrorArray = $errorRecord
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Error -ErrorRecord $errorRecord
    }
}

Out-File C:\ErrorArray.txt
```

Being new to PS, can anyone please point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a variable `$results` to hold errors you want to capture and pipe that out to a file. As well as that grab the string with error message - `$errorRecord.TargetObject` - rather than the entire error object.

```powershell
$results = @()

Get-ChildItem "\\Server\Share" -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable err

foreach ($errorRecord in $err)
{
    if ($errorRecord.Exception -is [System.IO.PathTooLongException])
    {
        Write-Warning ($errorRecord.TargetObject)
        $results += ,$errorRecord.TargetObject
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Error -ErrorRecord $errorRecord
    }
}

$results | Out-File C:\temp\ErrorArray.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't generate any information into the text file...

Comment: Do you get an error when writing to output file? Depending on OS/UAC settings you might not be able to write to root of C:, try a deeper location as per amended example. I amended result added to `$results` array to `$errorRecord.TargetObject` as the original message was not helpful. What PS version are you on?

Comment: That worked perfectly without the ".message".
I'm on version 3 btw. Thanks for your assistance.